# Colon in a custom function name causing error

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm new to Lisp and I'm currently trying to redo an old UCI Lisp program in Common Lisp. I'm having the following problem when I copy the following code (in funcs.lisp):

```
;;; HEADER-CD gets the head act of a CD form.
(defun header:cd 
    (x) 
    (car x))
```

The interpreter issues this error:

```
- READ from #<INPUT BUFFERED FILE-STREAM CHARACTER #P"funcs.lisp" @11>: there is no package
  with name "HEADER"
```

I do not understand the purpose for the colon in the code but I am guessing it's to specify the type of acceptable input since there is another function called "header:pair".

I'm not sure how to resolve this. Perhaps I could move to UCI lisp but I can't find its compiler/interpreter. Kindly help.

Comment: this form is for namespace prefixed symbols. what you can do, is to rename it to `header/cd` of `|header:cd|`

Comment: Thanks!! Do you know what the intended use for this notation was in UCI lisp, out of curiosity?

Comment: If it is legal it might be useful if you could add a pointer to the source of the program you're trying to modify.  I also could not find anything sensible for 'UCI Lisp' itself, although there are and were a vast number of lisps, so that might not be surprising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the colon in UCI Lisp for `header:cd` has any specific technical meaning. It's just an identifier and identifiers in UCI Lisp probably can (could -> it's a Lisp from the 70s which is no longer in use) use most of the ASCII character set, including the colon `:`. Here it might be a coding convention.

In Common Lisp the colon character has a special technical meaning in identifiers: it separates the package name from the symbol name. Note that UCI Lisp had no such feature as symbol packages.

Thus, I would simply translate an UCI-Lisp-identifier `header:cd` to `header-cd` in Common Lisp.

A slightly less useful way is to translate the UCI-Lisp-identifier `header:cd` to `|HEADER:CD|` or `HEADER\:CD` in Common Lisp. The vertical bars escape the symbol. The backslash escapes a single character in a symbol.

```
CL-USER 3 > '|HEADER:CD|
HEADER\:CD

CL-USER 4 > (symbol-name '|HEADER:CD|)
"HEADER:CD"
```

Answer (score 1):

The colon is used to specify a symbol package. In your case it means that the function cd should be in the package header. You should do the following:

```
(defpackage header) ; this creates the package header
(in-package :header) ; you move into that package so that it now becomes your working space
(defund cd (x)  ; define the function in header
  (car x) )
(export 'cd) ; this allows the function cd to be called from another package
(in-package :cl) ; now move to another package, i.e. the standard CL package
(header:cd '(1 2 3)) => 1 ; call the function cd from the other package
```

A bit convoluted, but when you study packages everything becomes more clear.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. I was unfamiliar with how the packages worked.

I don't think that the solution will work though because 'cd' is supposed to be a custom expression type and not a function. The function should be 'header'. This is why I thought the colon specifies the argument type. Sorry, this was not clear in my question. How do I proceed in this situation? I haven't defined cd yet. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

i would propose you to rearrange the data structure in a more 'common-lisp' way.

you could use structs, for example:

```
(defstruct cd header track-list)

CL-USER> (let ((cd (make-cd
                    :header "my cd 1"
                    :track-list (list "track 1" "track 2"))))
           (cd-header cd))
;;=> "my cd 1"
```